# Need advices on multiple query Amplify QraphQL

Tags: api, graphql, mutation, aws-amplify

I am developping an application using AWS Amplify.
I am using the Graphql API to manage my Dynamodb tables.

I need some advices to know the best way to mutate multiple Items in a table.
I read that Qraphql and dynamodb are able to mutate 1000 items per second, but actualy this performance is not working on my way :(.

To mutate multiple items i have an array with all my queries and input parameters, and i am using Promise.all function like :

```
await Promise.all(
  options.data.map(  item => 
     API.graphql(
       graphqlOperation(
          item.query, 
          { input: item.input }
       )
     )
   )
);
```

Is it the good way to do that ? it's working but with 1000 items it tooks 4/5 seconds.
Could you advice me how to improve the performance of multiple item mutation using Amplify graphQl API ?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try sending all your queries or mutations with 1 request instead of using `API.graphql` multiple times.

For example this how I delete the post's comments when I delete the post.

```
const commentMutations: any = comments.map(
  (comment: Comment, i: number) => {
    return `mutation${i}: deleteComment(input: {id: "${comment.id}"}) { id }`;
  }
);

await API.graphql(
  graphqlOperation(`
  mutation deletePostComments {
    ${commentMutations}
  }
`)
);
```

Comment: Hi LuckyTuvshee, thank you very much for your answer it seems pretty good. it's very nice to prepare all queries inside a const and use it one time in the graphql api.